# Fill offset(0,-1) until particular value is matched in VBA

Tags: excel, for-loop, vba

I am new in VBA and I am trying to solve one problem. I have Only Items column in Excel data like below. And I want to add code for each item which is in Code column.

```
Code  Items
      Animals:
AN    Cow
AN    Dog
AN    Zeebra
AN    Deer
      Flower:
FL    Rose
FL    Sunflower
      Fruit:
FR    Mango
FR    Banana
FR    Pineapple
FR    Cherry
```

I used following Loop for that

```
For Each Cell In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("B:B").Cells.Find(what:="Animal:", searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Offset(1, 0).Row & ":B" & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B").End(xlDown).Row)
If Cell.Value <> "Flower:" Then
Cell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = "AN"
ElseIf Cell.Value = "Flower:" Then
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = "FL"
End If
Next Cell
```

But, this is not acheiving what I need. can please someone let me know what to do in this case?

Answer (score 1):

This code uses a different approach (*do while*) but achieves what you want. It identifies the category by looking for a colon `:` within the cell. It then sets the `code` and applies it to the offset(0,-1) until a new code is found.

```
Sub FillOffset()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim i As Long
    i = 2
    Dim cell As Range
    Do Until i > ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If InStr(1, ws.Range("B" & i).Text, ":", vbTextCompare) Then
            Dim code As String
            code = UCase(Left(ws.Range("B" & i).Text, 2))
        Else
            ws.Range("B" & i).Offset(0, -1) = code
        End If

        i = i + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Sample output:

[image]

Comment: +1. This is a nice solution, with the added bonus of cars and operating systems.

Answer (score 1):

@mehow beat me by a a few seconds, but this code will also solve your problem.

```
Sub AddCodeForItems()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim code As String

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    lastRow = ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = ws.Range("B2:B" & lastRow)
    For Each cell In rng
        If Right(Trim(cell.Value), 1) = ":" Then
            code = UCase(Left(Trim(cell.Value), 2))
        Else
            cell.Offset(, -1).Value = code
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 sportsmanship and for the `right(, 1) = :` faster approach

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different approach:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim rngFound As Range
    Dim rngLast As Range
    Dim strFirst As String

    With ActiveSheet.Columns("B")
        Set rngFound = .Find(":", .Cells(.Cells.Count), xlValues, xlPart)
        If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
            strFirst = rngFound.Address
            Do
                Set rngLast = Range(rngFound.Offset(1), .Cells(.Cells.Count)).Find(":", , xlValues, xlPart)
                If rngLast Is Nothing Then Set rngLast = .Cells(.Cells.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                Range(rngFound.Offset(1, -1), rngLast.Offset(-1, -1)).Value = UCase(Left(rngFound.Text, 2))
                Set rngFound = Columns("B").Find(":", rngFound, xlValues, xlPart)
            Loop While rngFound.Address <> strFirst
        End If
    End With

    Set rngFound = Nothing
    Set rngLast = Nothing

End Sub
```